# Meaning of "curtain pulls"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, nouns

I have encountered curtain pulls used as a noun, seemingly to refer to pulled curtains. Is this a noun, is that what it refers to?

---

**The rays of moonlight shone through the gaps in between the curtain pulls, illuminating the boy's dormitory like a shiny diamond ring.**

---

The above passage is from a piece of Harry Potter fan fiction titled "Harry Potter and the Emerald Witch" by Lily Florette.

---

I feel that it's actually correct language and that I've encountered something like this before, but it still seems a little bit weird. Are there any other cases where pull is used as a noun, other than the usual of referring to the pull of an object, meaning the gravity of an object? With the same meaning as in this instance?

It apparently appears in *zipper pull* as well, meaning the same thing as *zipper* I think? Could you say *rope pull* as well?

And I know this might seem like a very specific and odd question, but it's often very specific and odd things like this which means the difference between being simply good at a language and understanding a language perfectly.

Comment: Readily found online or in dictionary

Comment: @DrMoishePippik At first I agreed with you, but when I tried searching for a link to a reputable dictionary definition to comment with, it appears to be less readily found than one might assume.  The Google results for "curtain pulls" seem to interpret the phrase as a verb, not a noun, and turn up references like this: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pull-the-curtains-blinds

Comment: As a noun, the term **curtain pulls** refers to cords attached to the wall on either side of a set of curtains.  The cords can be looped around a curtain to pull the curtain back away from the window.  In the US, they are usually called "curtain tie-backs" instead.  Dictionary link for "tie-back": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tieback

Comment: A **zipper pull** is that metal tab that you use to zip or unzip a zipper.  While the word "zipper" could refer either to this part, or the interconnecting teeth part, or both as a whole, "zipper pull" refers specifically to the tab.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck - a pull & a tie back are two different things.

Comment: You should give the source of the passage you are quoting. (Is it Harry Potter?)

Comment: @KateBunting The passage is from some Harry Potter fan fiction I was reading.

Comment: Thank you. Please edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 2):

A curtain pull is a stick or wand attached to the inside edge of a curtain - single or in pairs. Optionally removable or fixed in position.

[image]

<sup>This is the only image I could find of one in use, single curtain, not a pair as in the question</sup>

As a pair, these would hang to the inside edges, usually visible with the curtains in any position other than tightly closed.

Not to be confused with a pull-back, tie-back or hold-back, which are variations in how to hold the curtains open.

[image]

Just to complete the set, there's also a 'curtain pull cord' which is a complex string and pulley arrangement enabling you to open or close a pair of curtains by pulling a single cord attached to curtain rail & wall. You really can't see these unless you go poking around behind the curtains, so here's a diagram of the mechanism…

[image]

Comment: Nice illustrations!  In that case, I have never actually seen a “curtain pull” - although there is something similar for vertical blinds.

Comment: I've seen them in 'nice' hotels rather than domestic.